# Speed up Add Row function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following 'Add Row' Google Apps Script which triggers when a user clicks a button:

```js
//Add Row to Additional Duties Sheet
function AddRowtoAdditionalDutiesSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A4:X4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('A3:X4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, commentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('G4:K4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('G3:K4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('F3:F4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('R4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('R3:R4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('X4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('X3:X4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
}
```

This is a copy of my sheet which has columns A to X.

[image: Sample Sheet]

The script copies formulas in certain cells from row 4 to row 3 after the row has been inserted. The problem is that there are a lot of users populating the sheet and sometimes the formula doesn't paste into row 3. After a lot of observation, I believe it's because 2 different users click the button at the same time and the script is too slow to paste the formula. Is there a better way to write the script to make it faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In order to reduce the process cost of the script, I replaced `getActiveRange()` to the range.
- In order to continuously running the script, I set the LockService.

  - By this, when the button is clicked by several users, the script is locked, and each script running by each user can be run with the exclusive processing.

#### Modified script:

```
function AddRowtoAdditionalDutiesSheet() {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {
    try {

      // your script
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').getRow(), 1);
      spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('A4:X4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('A3:X4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
      spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').clear({contentsOnly: true, commentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
      spreadsheet.getRange('G4:K4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('G3:K4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
      spreadsheet.getRange('F4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('F3:F4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
      spreadsheet.getRange('R4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('R3:R4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
      spreadsheet.getRange('X4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('X3:X4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
      spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();

    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In your script, I think that using only the lock service, your issue might be resolved.

#### Reference:

- [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike - that's a clever idea. It works as I want it but the real test will be next Monday morning when there are 10 users in at once.

Comment: @McChief Thank you for replying. If an error occurs when 10 users are used, although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of it, for example, how about increasing `10000` of `if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {}`?

Comment: certain cells are still not pasting sometimes. I also noticed that the LockService is not activating the lock.

Comment: @McChief Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But about `certain cells are still not pasting sometimes. I also noticed that the LockService is not activating the lock.`, I cannot replicate your situation. Because in my tests, I couldn't see the same situation with you. In the current stage, I think that more information is required to think of the current issue. So by including the detail information for replicating your current issue, can you post it as new question? By this, I would like to confirm it and test it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @McChief Thank you for quick reply. I would like to confirm about the situation from your new question. Thank you, too.